# confused about Pascal syntax

Tags: pascal

I ran across this piece of pascal code. I am curious as to how this does not repeat endlessly.

```
repeat
  if xs>(torgx+xlim)
    then begin
      x:=xlim;
      BREAK;
    end;

  if xs<(torgx-xlim)
    then begin
      x:=0-xlim;
      BREAK;
    end;

  x:=xs-torgx; 
  BREAK;
until 0<>0;
```

I am confused as to how zero would ever be greater than or less than zero.

Comment: Doesn't "break" actually break out of the repeat-until loop? So I read it as the author wanted an infinite loop, with 3 easy methods for exiting. But it has been a few decades since I wrote any pascal...

Comment: Similar with writing "until false;", sometimes used when the loop is guaranteed to be exited from inside, with break for instance. This one exits before reaching the until, does not make sense to use any loop for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop that continues until `0 <> 0` is supposed to be endless.
But inside the loop there are some conditions that will break the loop, hence the use of the keyword `break`.

In fact, the `repeat..until` loop will only run once. The comparison is made that if a value is larger than a condition or less than another it will break out of the loop. If none of those conditions are met, it will break anyway.

Comment: Endless loops are not uncommon, but they often have an escape condition inside the loop. The exception from that rule can be found in the main loop of embedded environments, where the loop continues throughout the lifetime of the power on. In the case presented here, the loop is not needed at all.

Comment: It looks like something cobbled up to avoid using goto. Some things are uglier than goto :-)